# A [chip] off the old block

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[chip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chip) is a useless tag, exclusively used by people with no electronics knowledge, as a placeholder for the correct term. Which would be microcontroller, analog-to-digital converter etc: different forms of integrated circuits.

There's apparently also various other forms of "chip" used in JavaScript, as some stray questions about that use the tag.

---

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It does not describe the contents other than "vaguely hardware-related". It is very ambiguous.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Programming microcontrollers or PLDs is on-topic. But pure "chip" electronics questions are not and should be asked on the EE site instead. The same goes for questions in the borderland between firmware and hardware.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.

Comment: But I prefer my chips nicely fried alongside some fish, not burnt :(

Comment: Chips are also user interface elements in Material Design ([docs](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html)). Besides Angular, they also occur in Android development, and other Material Design implementations might also offer chips.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand the downvotes on this - I think that this is a good request.

This tag is used for everything from chip credit cards to electronics questions to Android questions, and there really isn't an objective way to decide which one is the "correct" usage.

This term clearly does *not* mean the same thing in all common contexts. It's also far too ambiguous to add anything meaningful to questions.

I say we burninate this.

Answer (score 2):

There are currenly only 69 questions using the tag, so this can be cleaned up by me and maybe a few others, as the simpler form of burnination described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/584518).

Most of the time, it should probably be replaced by [microcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microcontroller). Please also note that [microchip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microchip) is a bad tag, as that points to the manufacturer Microchip. Questions tagged Microchip should be re-tagged to [pic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pic) while we are at it.

All such questions should also have the [embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded) tag.

If someone who's good at JavaScript/Angular could go ahead and fix those questions, it would be appreciated, as that's not exactly my forte.

Comment: While I understand that 69 questions is relatively small, the specific limit for the abbreviated burnination process is <50 questions.

Comment: @Makyen I think the point here is that it can be done without involving diamond mods? I'd go ahead and clean it myself, but not before leaving this request here for a week or so.

Comment: Unfortunately, the directions are that any tag with >= 50 questions has to go through the whole process.

Comment: Only 68. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52926340) is clearly a s̵o̵f̵t̵hardware recommendation: "Can anyone suggest a chip that .." and should be closed. (Not sure what to replace the tag with, then.)

Comment: @usr2564301 Yes, that one should simply be closed as off-topic/recommendation question. It would be off-topic on the EE site too, being a part recommendation question.

Comment: There are currently just 48 questions in the tag. I am not sure if someone did a micro cleanup just to bring it below 50 questions. I still think it is fine if we move forward with the small tag burn here.

Comment: @BhargavRao I think I did some clean-up, not to bring it to a particular number, but because many questions with this tag are bad. I backed off from burninating this since there was no clear consensus. It's still a trash tag, though.

Comment: Yeah, I was also a bit confused as to why the community wasn't particularly interested to burn this. Perhaps we can leave it a few more days and see. Anyway, it is <50 posts, so it can be picked up anytime.

Comment: @BhargavRao I started to poke through the hardware/embedded questions now. Won't touch the Javascript ones.

Comment: Cool, sounds good. Checkout the https://stackoverflow.com/tags page, and search "chip" (no permalink, sorry), there seems to be a few more similarly named but better tags, that you can retag the posts with. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @BhargavRao I done the hardware questions, left the Android and Javascript alone. [tag:android-chips] looks like a good replacement for those.

Comment: And I cleaned the CV queue for the tag. I'll find some JS/Android guys for the others. Android does  seem straightforward, though.

Comment: There were 22 questions left, 8 of which were related to [tag:android-chips]. The Javascript ones were about [tag:chip-8]. 4 of them were about [tag:microchip], and were valid programming questions. Some 6 posts were remaining, closed the bad ones and deleted the worse ones.